# how to keep 1 url from rewrited after use .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

My htaccess file contains

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\s([^\s]+)\.php\s
RewriteRule .* %1.html [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^index.php$ http://%{http_host}/ver1 [R=301,L]
```

and it works fine

But my form action needs to point at a .php file

How do I prevent form.php from being rewritten?

I don't want the file form.php to be rewritten to form.html

Comment: I can't understand well what you wrote ... can you try to explain more please ?

Comment: in me htaccess all url like that php convert to html

but i need make 1 file not convert to html and keep it php

Comment: maybe adding this: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)form.php(.*)$`? I guess it will avoid the rewrite on `form.php` file, I'm not good with `htacess` so you have to try =)

Comment: Hi, I just edited the English in your post. StasGrin's answer below should work for you.

Comment: thx but no any idea for now
i try last answer but it keep 2 file
form.php and and form.html
and just need form.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this code **right after** first line:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)form.php(.*)$
```

This code check if there is any "form.php" in request string and if so - **aborts only next** RewriteRule.

EDIT:
Okay, my fault, i miseed 2 Rewrite Rules one straight after another. I format your code to a better one formation and description.. So try this one please:

```
RewriteEngine on

# 1st rule
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)form.php(.*)$
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\s([^\s]+)\.php\s
RewriteRule .* %1.html [R=301,L]

# 2nd rule
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)form.html(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php

# 3rd rule
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L]

# 4th rule
RewriteRule ^index.php$ http://%{http_host}/ver1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: both html and php file work :( i need make form.php work only with php

Comment: I checked this one on test domain. Yes - it works both with "form.php" and "form.html". So.. what's wrong?

Comment: Edited again. I added one more check. Now only "form.php" works as php code and "form.html" shown as html.